# How do you convert 4180 $\rm{J \cdot kg^{-1} K^{-1} to~ J\cdot kg^{-1} C^{-1}}$?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, units, si-units

I'm stuck because you can't simply -273.15 because it is the inverse of (temperature -273.15)

Comment: It is the same. The interval units of K and C are the same, even though the absolute values differ.

Comment: You don't need to convert it. I degree K is equal to one degree Celsius.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/292803/should-the-symbol-move-after-the-temperature-unit-to-indicate-addition-subtrac

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a trick question! Notice that the unit of Kelvin is essentially the same for the unit for Celsius, but is based around a different zero point. That is, an increase in one degree Celsius is the same as an increase in one Kelvin. Therefore, if something is 4180 per Kelvin, it is exactly the same as 4180 per Celsius.